# foreach loop syntax in tcl with error of foreach: Words not parenthesized

Tags: foreach, tcl

Error--> foreach: Words not parenthesized

How to fix the error? for below coding:

```
foreach name ( abc ) {
}
```

Comment: That executes the (empty) body of the foreach loop once, with variables `name` set to ( and `abc` set to ). No error messages, though it's probably not what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

What is giving you the error?  A linter program?

Parentheses do not function as a way to group an argument.  In Tcl, this is done with curly braces or double quotes.

```
foreach name { abc } {
}
```